# Setting up a color for each class of dataset generated by make_blobs

Tags: matplotlib, scatter

I am creating a series of datasets with make_blobs by changing the number of classes. I use plt.scatter to plot them. The color associated to all the data points is always black. I wonder if there is a way to assign a seperate color to points of each class? till I far what I have seen is examples like this `plt.scatter(,color='Red') but this didn't work for me and it is not exactly what I want.
This is my code:

```
X, Y = make_blobs(n_samples=n_samples, n_features=n_features, centers=n_classes)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker='o', c='Red', s=0.5, edgecolor='k')
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with makefiles as far as I can see... please remove the `makefile` tag, or make your question more clear, thanks!

Comment: Everything is black because you are using a small dot size and setting the edgecolor to black (`'k'`).  You can try to set the edgecolor to `'none'` to only see the main dot color.